# Onedrive and Dropbox simultaneous sync

Tags: sync, dropbox, onedrive

The business where I work has recently switched from OneDrive to Dropbox as cloud service, but people in the IT department were told to still use OneDrive (don't ask why, I don't know).  So my question is: "Is there a way to simultaneously sync those services? "

I mean if I upload a file in one service is there a way to upload to the other service, without doing it manually?

And the files that are already in OneDrive can be passed in Dropbox without having to do the whole process manually?

The OS we use at work is Windows 10

Everything is well accepted,  Powershell scripts,  programs...

Thank you

Comment: You can configure the OneDrive/DropBox folder to be the same folder as the OneDrive/DropBox folder.  This way you don't have duplicates of every file on your HDD.

Comment: Have you actually done what you suggested? Both Dropbox and OneDrive require you have a root folder with their respective service name (e.g.  Dropbox, or OneDrive). You can't configure both to have the same root without some sort of junction/symlink. One typically has to be a parent and the other a child. Thus my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the OneDrive folder inside Dropbox folder. That will be the easiest way. Except for IT, everyone else is going to use Dropbox, so that should be the most common installation scenario. After that, only IT will use OneDrive, so you should place OneDrive inside the Dropbox folder. I've done this specific setup before (OneDrive inside Dropbox) and it works fine.